# 2 SQL queries interlaced on ID number

Tags: python, sql, excel, report

I have a 2 queries that will be run repetitively to feed a report and some charts so need to make sure it is tight. First query has 25 columns and will yield out 25-50 rows from a massive table. My second query will result in another 25 columns (a couple matching columns) of 25 to 50 rows from another massive table.

Desired end result is a single document in that Query 1 (Problem) and Query 2 (Problem tasks) could match on a common column (Problem ID) so that row 1 is the problem, row 2-4 is the tasks, row 5 is the next problem and 6-9 are the tasks....ect. Now I realize I could do this manually by running the 2 queries and them just combining them in excel by hand, but looking for a eloquent process that could be reusable in my absence without too much overhead.

I was exploring inserts, union all, and cross join but the 2 queries have different columns that contain different critical data elements to be returned. Also, exploring setting up a Python job to do this by importing the CSVs and interlacing results but I am a early data science student and not yet much past creating charts from imported CSVs.

Any suggestions on how I might attack this challenge? Thanks for the help.
Picture of desired end result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtCm5.png)

Comment: SQL returns result sets where the columns are the same for all rows.  Although you might be able to contort the data in SQL, this type of operation is better done at the application layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something like

```
INSERT INTO target_table (<columns...>)
  SELECT <your first query> 
  UNION
  SELECT <your second query>
```

And then to retrieve data

```
SELECT * from target_table 
  WHERE <...>
  ORDER BY problem_id, task_id
```

Just ensure both queries return the same columns, i.e. the columns you want to populate in `target_table`, probably using fixed default values (e.g. the first query may return a default `task_id` by including `NULL as task_id` in the column list)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback @gimix, I ended up aliasing the columns that I was able to put together from the 2 tables (open_time vs date_opened ect...) so they all matched and selected '' for the null values I needed to.  I unioned the 2 selected statements as suggested, Then I finally realized I can just insert my filtering queries twice as sub queries. It will now be nice and quickly repeatable for pulling and dropping into excel 2x per week.  Thank you!

Comment: This answer should have been left as a comment to the person you wanted to reply to.